# Get an incentive for NOT saying "look at the documentation"

Tags: feature-request, link-only-answers, incentive

When a user *clearly* states that they are a newbie, people should be encouraged to give an interpretation of the documentation, not just a link to the documentation. Increasingly, Stack Overflow is the goto place for many people on coding courses, and although many may think this is a bad thing, for the community it is a good thing.

Comment: The documentation is the very first source of information any developer should look at. Why should we stop pointing at it? If it's done rudely or non-constructively, that's another issue. But the link itself is valid.

Comment: How would one implement such a feature, exactly?

Comment: If a user needs help understanding the documentation they've already tried to read, they should say so and explain which bit they're having trouble with - at which point I'm sure such help will be provided. If the user expects the community to *take the place* of documentation, that's an appalling expectation.

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Chris! To preemptively respond to your next question, nothing is wrong with the way you wrote this request. By convention, voting on this site often [represents opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Arg. This actively *encourages* people to *not* read the proper documentation *and* discourages people from helping people access it!

Comment: As a newbie who is not afraid to say so and ask, yes, some of my questions have been related to simple stuff that -in hind sight- the documentation answers. However as a newbie, I search this site and ONLY ask the question if the documentation is confusing OR

Comment: oops - newbie at this also.....   OR the link only answer in the answer points to a really interesting sounding answer in a place that no longer exists. And saying that this is a forum for experts does not make it so. Too many coding schools have picked up on this and it is now pushed as a place to find your question previously asked and "hopefully" answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This principle holds even when it's *not* a newbie asking the question. Posting a bare link to the documentation in lieu of an answer is rarely if ever a good response.

We actually block answers that consist only of bare links, and automatically flag answers that consist of little more as [low-quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/). If you come across such an answer, don't hesitate to encourage the author to expand on it.

See also: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I assumed the OP was referring to comments, not answers

Comment: I think posting a link as a comment is fine. However not all answers that are little more than a link are off-limits, apparently. I flagged [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028800/sql-join-multiple-tables-to-return-rows-as-columns/12028919#12028919) and it was rejected. I didn't think the "answer" was very helpful without a code sample, and thought it should have been converted to a comment instead. Other answers pointed to the same documentation *and* posted a relevant code sample. <shrug>

Comment: It's a tough call, @Aaron - that may not be a great answer, but it at least does provide enough information to retain whatever value it has should the link break.

Comment: I disagree - "use the PIVOT command" on its own is not very helpful, especially relative to other answers on the same page that said the same thing *and* included code samples that give the user some help on how to use the PIVOT command. I could post answers all day that say "Use CROSS APPLY" or "Use table partitioning" or "Use a GUID" - even with links, how are these helpful? They sound more like comments than answers to me. An answer shouldn't just name the technology to use.

Comment: So down-vote it then, @Aaron. There's a difference between a bad answer and an answer that, once MSDN is restructured, won't be an answer at all.

Comment: I think this one is both. And I have down-voted it. My point in commenting is exactly what you stated - it's a tough call. Different moderators (or maybe even the same mods on different days) may not always find the same link-only or largely link-only answer to be "not an answer."

Answer (score 7):

There needs to a check on users who want to use Stack Overflow as a proxy for doing their own basic research.  Otherwise, the site becomes flooded with basic questions, many of which are not very good questions because the OP didn't get a basic education on their craft.

A site filled with poorly-worded basic questions is a turnoff for the experts, which is who we want to attract.  No experts, no answers.

Consequently, embellishing a link-only answer to a basic question that's easily answered by reading the documentation is the moral equivalent of  polishing a turd.

If you really want to be helpful to the OP, provide a link to the appropriate documentation *in a comment* below the question.  Then, vote to close as Too Localized.

Comment: I have no problem with basic questions, but basic shouldn't mean "I can't be bothered to even try reading docs."

Comment: @Shog9: tl;dr: "No, thank you."

Comment: I had to read this twice, but I think Robert is saying that there's nothing wrong with encouraging people to look at documentation in some cases. (In accordance with politeness rules and such, of course.) @Shog9

Comment: I added a paragraph (or two).  Hopefully, this clarifies my position. :P

Comment: Ok, sure. Linking to the documentation is good, always. But I still don't like link-only answers. You've no idea how many broken MSDN links I've cursed over the years - maybe they did originally answer the question, clearly and completely, but without any explanation of *how*, that link benefited only the ("turd"-posting) OP.